# Android development google maps loads but not showing location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Everything worked just fine. A few days ago a problem occured with all of my applications using google map services. As far as i'm concered, there's no problem with the code.

When i open a map activity like:

```
String uriBegin = "geo:" + "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312";
    String query = "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312" + "(" + DeviceId
            + ")";

    String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
    String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    intent.putExtra("DeviceId", DeviceId);

    startActivity(intent);
```

It loads google maps, everything, locates my phone's location, goes to the location: 47.531605, 21.627312 but it doesn't mark it, and says: no matches.

I hope somebody got some answers :)
Regards,

Comment: What do you get in your LogCat?

Comment: I run it on my phone, so i don't have log cat, can't start android emulator in my adb. But will work on it

Comment: What if you plug your device to your PC and run your code in it?

Comment: Where are you actually adding your marker?

Comment: That code places a marker on Google Maps, somewhere in Debrecen. The name of the Marker is "DeviceId". It is working fine for me.

Comment: Do you just want to add a marker at that lat/lng? + what zgc7009 said

Comment: It should work like joao2fast4u said, i can't add markers in the google maps activity, because it opens a link, not an activity in my case, though it is also bad for me. Maybe Intent.setclassname could help? isn't it?
joao2fast4u could you send me your working code? jtomi92@hotmail.com
thanks,

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yn9q650bze35jhn/Sim908_Control_app.zip
Here is the app, could not find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any where in your code where you are adding a marker.

Below is a method which will add a marker to your map at the given lat/lng.

```
public void addMarker(Double Lat, Double Long, String Title, String Snippet) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Lat, Long))
                .title(Title)
                .draggable(true)
                .snippet(Snippet)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
    }
```

where `mMap` is your Google map object.

Comment: this should be in the google maps activity, not in my main activity where i call the googlemaps intent. it opens a url link, not a activity i guess, so i can't place these markers.
maybe intent.setclassname could help?

Answer (score 0):

I just change this:

```
String uriBegin = "geo:" + "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312";
String query = "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312" + "(" + DeviceId
        + ")";
```

to this:

```
String uriBegin = "geo:" + "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312";
String query = "47.531605" + "," + "21.627312";
```

and it works fine. I'm ragequiting.